# New Azure Resource group powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have installed Azure powershell 1.0.0 released 3 days ago. and trying to create a new azure resource group using this command
`New-AzureRMResourceGroup`

Before this when I run Login-AzureRMAccount and supply it with my subscription ID(as I am linked with more than one subscription).

```
Login-AzureRMAccount -SubscriptionID ""
```

This strangely tells me , my email id does not have rights to this subscription. It's weird because I can login to this subscription alright and can do things through portal.

When I try to do this using `Set-AzureSubscription` `Select-AzureSubscription` and then create resource group. New Resource group is always created in my first subscription... Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and following [this thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1253) led me to provide the `-tenantID` parameter in addition to the `-subscriptionID` of the desired subscription to the `Login-AzureRMAccount` cmdlet, and got around the issue.

New items began to appear under the account I was expecting.